# Accessing angular library from angular app - StaticInjectorError in angular component with ElementRef in constructor

Tags: angular, angular-library, ng-modules

I created angular library (named ng-library) by following https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries.

- Built it usin `ng build ng-library`
- Made it available to other angular applications using `yarn link`
- Created an angular application and linked the library using `yarn link ng-library`

I could use the components and services inside the module. Everything fine!

Now I added a new angular component in ng-library which is using ElementRef.

```
import { Component, NgZone, Input, Output, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ElementRef, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'new-component',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class NewComponent {
  protected el: HTMLElement;

  constructor(r: ElementRef, protected z: NgZone) {
    this.el = r.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

I tried using this component in angular application created. I am getting below error.

```
AppComponent.html:1 ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NewComponent-> ElementRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NewComponent -> ElementRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36417:27)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51335:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51261:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51111:20)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51335:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51261:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51111:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62298:29)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63364:16)
    at resolveDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63895:45)
```

This is how I added the module in my Angular application.

```
import { NgLibraryModule } from "ng-library";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, NgLibraryModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Error says provider for ElementRef not available. How can I make ElementRef available in the NgModule which is inside an Angular Library?

Thanks
Basanth

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ElementRef` with the `@ViewChild` decorator: 
Example : 
`@ViewChild('idOfTheDiv/ButtonAsInYourHTML',{ static: true }) private idOfTheDiv/Button:ElementRef;`

You can read more here https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/

Comment: link is not working try this one https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-viewchild-access-component